# max_length does not work

Tags: python, django

I have such field in my model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Anonymous')
```

But when I enter more characters in that field, there is no errors, I can enter any amount of characters. And I can do it in my view, do it in admin/, there is no errors anyway.
Somebody adviced me to make .full_clean() before saving entries, but it does not affect, this field still allows to enter more than 20 characters. Same with other fields.

And I very, very, very sorry for my bad english.

UPD:
Full code of my models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import imgboard.const as c

fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/static/img')


class Board(models.Model):
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    # Short description to be displayed on index page
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Short description")
    # Is namefags allowed in this thread
    names_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Custom names is allowed")
    default_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Anonymous')
    # Description to be displayed in header of board page
    verbose_description = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='')
    # Allowed extensions of files that can be uploaded to this board
    allowed_extensions = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default=c.ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS)
    # Number of a thread, that will be pinned to top.
    pinned_thread_id = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    # Is threads w/o pic allowed
    file_required = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="File is required")

    def __str__(self):
        return '/'+self.addr+'/ - '+self.description

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['addr']


class Thread(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, db_column='addr', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Anonymous')
    last_msg_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Time of last message published in this thread',
                                         auto_now_add=True)
    pic = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    sage_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bumps = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-last_msg_date']


class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Anonymous')
    pic = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # OP-post mark displays, that this message was written by thread creator
    op_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Sage mark displays, that thread will not be bumped by this message
    sage = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

Migration is ran much times, because I wrote "max_length" a long long ago, but noticed this bug just now.
About DB schemas, I heard that sqlite doesn't limit VARCHAR's at all, max_length is only for Django backend.

Comment: There is surely another peace of code that causing the problem. Post other part of you model if it's related. If there are none, try to check you DB schema to have max length in it (e.g. see it in pgadmin if you are Postgres).

Comment: did you run migration after changing the field???

Comment: We need you to post more context, like if you did migrations or if you're using django forms so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all databases such feature as limited string length. In this particular case I was using SQLite which doesn't.
So, `max_length` affects only in case of using other databases, such as PostgreSQL.

If you need to limit field length in Django, consider using `validators` keyword argument of a field to define validator which will check if passes string is not too long and raise ValidationException if it is.

Also, SQLite often isn't suitable in production, so if you're using it only on development stage, consider to use actual database you use on production on test environment too. Just because of such differences: you could think that everything is ok with your project, but get a bug on production because of such circumstances.